# Calling a function within a function causing problems in execution

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter

I am building a snake game using Tkinter only, and I managed to make a working game. The code works perfectly, until I added a start menu to show up before the game. To do this, I encased all my functions within one function called play(), and when I run the code, a menu shows up as expected, and when clicked play the window closes and the game itself shows up.

However, the keybinds for left/right/up/down to control the snake no longer works. I have checked that I have called the correct functions within my mainloop, and I have also tried moving it outside of the mainloop but it throws a referenced before assigned error.

Is there a logic error that I am missing? I am a beginner to Python and the Tkinter module so that is quite likely. Here is my code (where I suspect the problem is):

````
def play():
#some other functions including moveSnake and placeFood

    def leftKey(event):
        global direction
        direction = "left"

    def rightKey(event):
        global direction
        direction = "right"

    def upKey(event):
        global direction
        direction = "up"

    def downKey(event):
        global direction
        direction = "down"

    snake = []
    snakeSize = 15
    snake.append(canvas.create_rectangle(snakeSize,snakeSize, snakeSize * 2, snakeSize * 2, fill="white", outline = ""))

    score = 0
    txt = "Score:" + str(score)
    scoreText = canvas.create_text(width/2, 20, fill="white", font="Helvetica 20 bold", text=txt)

    canvas.bind("<Left>", leftKey)
    canvas.bind("<Right>", rightKey)
    canvas.bind("<Up>", upKey)
    canvas.bind("<Down>", downKey)
    canvas.focus_set()

    direction = "right"


    placeFood()
    moveSnake()
    window.mainloop()

#new window/start menu
window1 = Tk()
window1.geometry('600x800')
window1.title("Snake")

#play button
playButton = Button(window1,text="Play", command = play)
playButton.pack(side=TOP)

#leaderboard button
leaderboardButton = Button(window1,text="Leaderboard", command = viewleaderboard)
leaderboardButton.pack(side=TOP)

#settings button
playButton = Button(window1,text="Settings", command = viewsettings)
playButton.pack(side=TOP)

window1.mainloop() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it without needing to create a class. I moved my keybinds to my main script, right below I created window1. Then I reassigned the bind to the 'window', opposed to 'canvas'. The purpose being that the keybinds were not being called to the correct place. I also add global score and global direction, to avoid it being unrecognised. This fixed my code, though I'm sure it can be optimised much further. Hope it helps out another newbie like me!

** To clarify, 'window' is my original window in which the game lies in and is defined in a function which I have not listed, it is separate to window1 **

```
    global score
    score = 0
    txt = "Score:" + str(score)
    scoreText = canvas.create_text(width/2, 20, fill="white", font="Helvetica 20 bold", text=txt)

    window.bind("<Left>", leftKey)
    window.bind("<Right>", rightKey)
    window.bind("<Up>", upKey)
    window.bind("<Down>", downKey)
    window.focus_set()
    global direction
    direction = "right"
```